# Reverse for 'user_logout' not found, though it was configured well

Tags: django

I have such a navbar:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:10px" >
    <li><a href="{% url 'account:user_logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

It report error:

```
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'user_logout' not found. 'user_logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

However, the `user_logout` was configured finely.

```
    url(r"^logout/$",auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="account/logout.html"),name="user_logout"),
```

and the namespace:

```
url(r"^account/", include("account.urls", namespace='account', app_name='account')),
```

It seems that there's no reasons to report error `Reverse for 'user_logout' not found`.

it works if use absolute path:

```
<li><a href="/account/logout/">Logout</a></li>
```

and `<li><a href="{% url 'account:user_logout' %}">Logout</a></li>` perform properly in other template like base.html

What's might be the problem?

Comment: How do you render the template that causes the error?

Comment: Do you use this "account:user_logout" in account app or in another app? If in account app, possibly you should write just like  `<a href="{% url 'user_logout' %}">Logout</a>`
Also it is strange to send template name to class-based function.
just add it in function
then it will be like     url(r"^logout/$",auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name="user_logout"),

class LogoutView(...):
    template_name="account/logout.html"

Comment: What is the page that you are getting when you hit `yourhostadrr/logout/`?